# SQL LIKE query to match any single word in a string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-like

I am trying to query:

```
$title2 = (isset($row_DetailRS1['r_bus_name']) ? $row_DetailRS1['r_bus_name'] : "");

$query_test = "SELECT * 
                 FROM table 
                WHERE r_email = '$email2' 
                  AND r_city != '$location2' 
                  AND r_bus_name LIKE '%$title2%' 
             ORDER BY r_bus_name";
```

The `r_bus_name LIKE '%$title2'` is defined from above and is grabbing the TITLE of the EVENT from the POST. The title is usually two to three words...

How do I query `r_bus_name LIKE (any of the words in the event title $title2)`?

Because right now it is taking the whole value of $title2.. I need to split them up or explode them in words, so if the title is something like "Test title here" then "Tester title here" would match?

Comment: Make sure you correct for SQL injection when you update this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to search on *EACH* of the words in the title, you would need to construct a query using *OR* operations to apply them to the same query.

It might look something like this:

```
// break apart the title using spaces
$title2 = (isset($row_DetailRS1['r_bus_name']) ? $row_DetailRS1['r_bus_name'] : "");
$title_keywords = explode(" ", $title2);

// construct conditions (Note the ampersand causes pass-by-reference)
foreach($title_keywords as &$keyword) {
    $keyword = "r_bus_name LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($keyword)."%'";
}
$keyword_search = "(" . implode(" OR ", $title_keywords) . ")";

$query_test = "SELECT * 
    FROM table 
    WHERE r_email = '".mysql_real_escape_string($email2)."' 
        AND r_city != '".mysql_real_escape_string($location2)."' 
        AND ".$keyword_search." 
    ORDER BY r_bus_name";

// ...
```

Comment: GREAT STUFF!! That was perfect!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the table is MyISAM, you could use the [native Full Text Search (FTS) functionality](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-query-expansion.html):

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT t.* 
                    FROM YOUR_TABLE t
                   WHERE t.r_email = '%s' 
                     AND t.r_city != '%s' 
                     AND MATCH(t.r_bus_name) AGAINST('%s')
                ORDER BY t.r_bus_name",
                 mysql_real_escape_string($email2),
                 mysql_real_escape_string($location2),
                 mysql_real_escape_string($title2) );

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Sadly, MySQL doesn't support FTS on the InnoDB engine.

### Addendum

I recommend using [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) if you aren't using PDO/etc for prepared statements, to protect against SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Split title2 on spaces and do multiple likes:

```
$titleArray = split(" ", $title2);

$query_test = "SELECT * 
                 FROM table 
                WHERE r_email = '$email2' 
                 AND r_city != '$location2'
                 AND ("
    foreach ($title as titleArray)
        $query_test .= "OR r_bus_name LIKE '%$title%'" 
$query_test .= "ORDER BY r_bus_name";
```

Comment: You will want to change your AND to OR so each of the `%$title%`'s will be found. Otherwise it will look for ALL of them.

Comment: cdburgess is correct - I corrected what I can, but additional logic is needed so the `OR` isn't there on the first value in the array.